# Is it legal to issue free stock?

Tags: united-states, stocks, shares, corporation

Are there legal obstacles to issuing free stock? Along with no promise of any return. Do you still need to be a corporation to do so?

The money comes from payments made elsewhere for products and services, not as investments. It is then distributed to the owners of the free stock. Nothing determines their rate of return except for how many free stock values they own. They can "purchase" another stock value daily.

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: It's very likely legal to give out free pieces of paper that say "_This piece of paper has no value_" on them, but such pieces of paper would not be "stock" by its normal definition. Whether giving out "traditionally defined" stock for free (where each stock represents a part-ownership of some corporate entity) is a different question, but not – as far as I can tell – what you're asking. I think you'll need to clarify exactly what you're trying to do to get a more meaningful answer.

Comment: "The money comes from payments" - what money? I thought the stock was free.

Comment: @TripeHound and Philipp- my interpretation of this question is that the stock has value, but it's being given away for free rather than sold.

Comment: What's the relationship between the company and stock owners here?  Why is the company giving them money?  Do they work for the company, is the company giving away the money as charity?

Comment: @Philipp- the money comes from coincidental payments made at the location at where the free stock is given away. The payments purchase an item or service that is unrelated to the stock and don't affect the rate of return for the buyer.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian- the relationship between the company and stock owners is simply that the stock owners receive dividends from the company. The income that pays the dividends is produced by the coincidental payments made by the consumers-- which also become shareholders themselves. In that way I guess the system can be defined as equity crowdfunding, but minimal or no need to be regulated because the stocks themselves are free.

Comment: @Nosjack- the country in question is the United States

Comment: @JohnHansen *"The income that pays the dividends is produced by the coincidental payments made by the consumers-- which also become shareholders themselves"* -  That sounds a lot like a [ponzi scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzi_scheme), if you ask me.

Comment: @Philipp- its not a ponzi scheme because, if the consumer chooses, they can receive the stock for free. They just have to commute to a location to receive the stock and at that location it's likely they make an unrelated purchase. Commission from the purchase grows the stock issuer's revenue and dividends are given to shareholders regardless of whether or not they made an unrelated purchase for an item or service.

Comment: A ponzi scheme involves a false accounting of income or gain. This scheme is more like multi-level-marketing.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., SEC Rule 504, as one possible method, allows the issue of unregistered stock to non-accredited investors. There's a $5 million limit effectively per 18 month time period. A notice of a stock-issue must be filed which is a Form D. However, each state can add limits and conditions and each state will likely require at least a Form D. Most states limit the number of stockholders to a small number but a few states have no limits.

Now the corporation must be organized with a state.

To have fewer limits on a stock-issue would require that the stock-issue be registered, both federally and by the states, but there is a system of a standardized prospectus form that can be used.

And any document or accounting representing a share or percentage of something shared with other stakeholders is a security and is regulated. Alternatives would be an account with a merchant, relative to the merchant's business, and not related to other customer accounts with the merchant. Another alternative would be gifts to the customer not shared with other customers and not a percentage position in the business.

Comment: Very well written.